# What is the different between Trace.Warn(ex.Message.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); and Trace.Warn(ex.Message.ToString());

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Warn(ex.Message.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        }
```

What will happen if i use the below code, i mean with out write CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Warn(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation for String.ToString(IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2.aspx):

> Returns this instance of String; no actual conversion is performed.

So, there is no difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.

The Culture is not specific to operations like `Trace`. 
It is specific to the current thread.
In other words, there should ideally be NO difference in the above two statements.

More information and Sample code is available here : [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

Comment: Almost answers the question. But not exactly.

Comment: @SURESH K: Does this help answer your question?